# Another Tomcat/PermGen nightmare; Tomcat won't start

Tags: tomcat

i've gotten PermGen out of space errors in the past and would just restart tomcat to fix it.
but now Tomcat won't start at all.
it's tomcat 5.5

```
Exception: java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: PermGen space
Exception: null
Exception in thread "http-8080-Processor15" java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: PermGen space
Exception in thread "http-8080-Processor17" java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: PermGen space
Exception in thread "http-8080-Processor22" java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: PermGen space
Exception in thread "http-8080-Processor16" java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: PermGen space
Exception in thread "http-8080-Processor20" java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: PermGen space
Exception: java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: PermGen space
Exception in thread "http-8080-Processor21" java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: PermGen space
Exception in thread "http-8080-Processor24" java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: PermGen space
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina
        at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:200)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:188)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:303)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:248)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.init(Bootstrap.java:222)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.main(Bootstrap.java:410)
```

here's the output when i try to start tomcat

```
  cygwin=false
+ os400=false
+ darwin=false
+ case "uname" in
++ uname
+ '[' -z /usr/share/tomcat5 ']'
+ JAVADIR=/usr/share/java
+ PRG=/usr/bin/dtomcat5
+ '[' -h /usr/bin/dtomcat5 ']'
++ dirname /usr/bin/dtomcat5
+ PRGDIR=/usr/bin
+ '[' -z /usr/share/tomcat5 ']'
+ '[' -r /usr/share/tomcat5/bin/setenv.sh ']'
+ false
+ false
+ '[' -z /usr/share/tomcat5 ']'
+ '[' -z /usr/java/jdk1.6.0_20 ']'
+ _RUNJAVA=/usr/java/jdk1.6.0_20/bin/java
+ _RUNJAVAC=/usr/java/jdk1.6.0_20/bin/javac
+ _RUNJDB=/usr/java/jdk1.6.0_20/bin/jdb
+ CLASSPATH=/usr/java/jdk1.6.0_20/lib/tools.jar
+ '[' -n '' ']'
+ '[' -r /usr/share/java/jsse/jcert.jar ']'
++ /usr/bin/build-classpath mx4j/mx4j-impl
++ /usr/bin/build-classpath mx4j/mx4j-jmx
+ CLASSPATH=/usr/java/jdk1.6.0_20/lib/tools.jar:/usr/share/tomcat5/bin/bootstrap.jar:/usr/share/tomcat5/bin/commons-logging-api.jar:/usr/share/java/mx4j/mx4j-impl.jar:/usr/share/java/mx4j/mx4j-jmx.jar
+ '[' -z '' ']'
+ CATALINA_BASE=/usr/share/tomcat5
+ '[' -z '' ']'
+ CATALINA_TMPDIR=/usr/share/tomcat5/temp
+ have_tty=0
++ tty
+ '[' /dev/pts/0 '!=' 'not a tty' ']'
+ have_tty=1
+ '[' -z '' ']'
+ export CATALINA_PID=/var/run/tomcat5.pid
+ CATALINA_PID=/var/run/tomcat5.pid
+ false
+ '[' -r /usr/share/tomcat5/bin/tomcat-juli.jar ']'
+ JAVA_OPTS='-Xms128m -Xmx256m -XX:PermSize=512m -XX:MaxPermSize=512m -Djava.util.logging.manager=org.apache.juli.ClassLoaderLogManager -Djava.util.logging.config.file=/usr/share/tomcat5/conf/logging.properties'
+ '[' 1 -eq 1 ']'
+ echo 'Using CATALINA_BASE:   /usr/share/tomcat5'
Using CATALINA_BASE:   /usr/share/tomcat5
+ echo 'Using CATALINA_HOME:   /usr/share/tomcat5'
Using CATALINA_HOME:   /usr/share/tomcat5
+ echo 'Using CATALINA_TMPDIR: /usr/share/tomcat5/temp'
Using CATALINA_TMPDIR: /usr/share/tomcat5/temp
+ '[' start = debug -o start = javac ']'
+ echo 'Using JRE_HOME:       /usr/java/jdk1.6.0_17'
Using JRE_HOME:       /usr/java/jdk1.6.0_17
+ '[' start = jpda ']'
+ '[' start = debug ']'
+ '[' start = run ']'
+ '[' start = start ']'
+ shift
+ touch /usr/share/tomcat5/logs/catalina.out
+ '[' '' = -security ']'
+ /usr/java/jdk1.6.0_20/bin/java -Xms128m -Xmx256m -XX:PermSize=512m -XX:MaxPermSize=512m -Djava.util.logging.manager=org.apache.juli.ClassLoaderLogManager -Djava.util.logging.config.file=/usr/share/tomcat5/conf/logging.properties -Djava.endorsed.dirs= -classpath /usr/java/jdk1.6.0_20/lib/tools.jar:/usr/share/tomcat5/bin/bootstrap.jar:/usr/share/tomcat5/bin/commons-logging-api.jar:/usr/share/java/mx4j/mx4j-impl.jar:/usr/share/java/mx4j/mx4j-jmx.jar -Dcatalina.base=/usr/share/tomcat5 -Dcatalina.home=/usr/share/tomcat5 -Djava.io.tmpdir=/usr/share/tomcat5/temp org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap start
+ '[' '!' -z /var/run/tomcat5.pid ']'
+ echo 3662
```

I think my JAVA_OPTS look ok, but it's still not starting.
does anyone see a problem...
thanks

Comment: Seems unusual that the same log shows -XX:MaxPermSize=512m and -XX:MaxPermSize=128m in the startup - how would you be sure whats the correct value.

Comment: that was bad my edit; it did  say -XX:PermSize=512m -XX:MaxPermSize:512m.